# How to hover over (mouseover) an element in Selenium Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation

Anyone know how to hover over an element in Selenium Ruby Webdriver?

My code is like this:

```
el = driver.find_element(:css => "#foo")
driver.move_to el # How do I trigger a mouseover event on this element?
```

I'm using selenium-webdriver gem with Firefox in Linux 32-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the answer is:

```
driver.move_to(el).perform
```

I forgot the `.perform`.

Comment: Check @Seanny123 and my comment there about why this may now work.

Answer (score 6):

I used `driver.action.move_to(el).perform` which differs ever so slightly from the other answers, so I thought I would include it for completeness sake.

Comment: currently selenium has forked off the `move_to` function so you need to use `.action` to access the mouse functions now.

Comment: @DanSabin would you like to propose an edit clarifying this? I would totally accept it.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
driver.mouse.move_to el
```

Comment: Check @Seanny123 and my comment below on the answer about why this may now work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Selenium's Action Builder](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html) to access more complex actions like hovering (which is what seanny123's answer is demonstrating).

Also, if you are working with a hover, odds are you will need to dynamically wait for it to display before taking your next action (e.g., using an explicit wait).

I put together an example on how to do this -- you can see the full write-up [here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/50-hovers).

Answer (score 1):

To hover an element:

```
driver.action.move_to(element).perform
# e.g.    
driver.action.move_to(driver.find_element(css: 'a')).perform
```

To hover an element at a specific location:

```
driver.action.move_to(element, mouse_x, mouse_y).perform
# e.g.    
driver.action.move_to(driver.find_element(css: 'a'), 100, 100).perform
```