# How can I use Selenium to hover over an element in order to make it visible so I can click a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec

There are many similar posts asking this question:

[How to hover over (mouseover) an element in Selenium Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265310/how-to-hover-over-mouseover-an-element-in-selenium-ruby)

[Selenium2 WebDriver Ruby => how click on a hidden link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777886/selenium2-webdriver-ruby-how-click-on-a-hidden-link)

[Ruby Mouse Over is not long enough, may need a delay of some sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564716/ruby-mouse-over-is-not-long-enough-may-need-a-delay-of-some-sort)

[Code for mouse over action.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/webdriver/hover/webdriver/6WPwhP36EkU/S-H-APhuOpgJ)

I have `div.rating-panel` that is hidden until `div.empty-stars-container` is hovered over. I want to simulate the user hovering over `div.empty-stars-container` and then clicking a couple links in the `div.rating-panel`.

```
it "should create rating items" , :js => true do
  # wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds

  empty_stars = page.driver.browser.find_element(:css, "h1 .empty-stars-container")
  star_3 = page.driver.browser.find_element(:css, "h1 a#panel_1_star_3")
  new_save = page.driver.browser.find_element(:css, "input#new_save")

  page.driver.browser.action.move_to(empty_stars).perform
  # wait.until { star_3.displayed? == true }

  star_3.click
  new_save.click

  page.should have_css("div.user-stars-container")
end
```

The browser opens, and the `move_to` action is performed (I assume) but the panel never becomes visible! I tried to `wait.until` but that just caused a timeout.

The test fails at `star_3.click` with the error message

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I would hope there is a way to do what I am trying to do, because there are many javascript tests in my application, and I hoped Selenium would provide the help necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: what language is this? also why did you comment out the # wait.until { star_3.displayed? == true }

Comment: I am developing in Ruby on Rails. I am using Rspec for my testing environment, with Capybara and Selenium. I commented out the wait.until because it shouldn't be necessary. The tests fails when it gets to star_3.click in this case. When I un-comment the wait.until, the tests fails in that block due to a timeout ; the element is never displayed.

Comment: Currently in my test, the move_to(empty_stars) is performed, but for some reason it does not cause the panel to become visible. So, if I un-comment wait.until then I can manually hover over the element in the 10 seconds and the rest of the test will run and pass.

Comment: Ah ok. This may be a dumb question considering your research points this out, but have you tried a empty_stars.click? Also this might just be more of the same...but have you tried the mouse_over api? I was able to find it here http://selenium-client.rubyforge.org/